# Knockoutjs Button Click

Tags: asp.net-mvc, knockout.js

Hi how can ı get my value with knockoutjs click event my button code

```
 <button data-bind="click : LikeButtonClick , value : MessageId" class="btn btn-default like"><span data-bind="text:LikeCount"></span> <i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i></button>
```

and my knockoutjs click code

```
 var LikeButtonClick = function () {
    alert("");
 }
```

---

And how can I refresh my likes after like button click event. I use template binding. My template binding code is

```
  var viewModel = {
            messages: ko.observableArray()
        };
        ko.options.useOnlyNativeEvents = true;
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("statusMessages", "Home")', function (data) {
            viewModel.messages(data);
        });
```

and my like button code

```
var LikeButtonClick = function (id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/Like/' + id,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                        // refresh
                        });
                }
            });
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

Another method is to build the click function into your data model. Here I've added the function to the item directly. Each click will only affect it's own object information.

```js
function Post() {
  var self = this;
  self.Text = ko.observable("Lorem Ipsum");
  self.Liked = ko.observable(false);
  self.LikeCount = ko.computed(function() {
    return self.Liked() ? 1 : 0;
  });
  self.MessageId = ko.observable(1);


  self.LikeButtonClick = function() {
    self.Liked(!self.Liked());
  }

}

function viewModel() {
  var self = this;

  self.Posts = ko.observableArray();

  self.Load = function() {
    self.Posts.push(new Post());
    self.Posts.push(new Post());
    self.Posts.push(new Post());
  }
  self.Load();
}

ko.applyBindings(new viewModel());
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/knockout/3.4.2/knockout-min.js"></script>

<div data-bind="foreach: Posts">

  <div data-bind="text:Text"></div>
  <button data-bind="click: LikeButtonClick, value: MessageId" class="btn btn-default like">
<span data-bind="text:LikeCount"></span>
<i class="fa fa-thumbs-o-up"></i></button>
</div>
```

Comment: How can ı refresh my binding tempalte after like button click

Comment: my template code var viewModel = {
            messages : ko.observableArray()
        };
        ko.options.useOnlyNativeEvents = true;
        ko.applyBindings(viewModel);
        $.getJSON('@Url.Action("statusMessages", "Home")', function (data) {
            viewModel.messages(data);
        });

Comment: and my like function var LikeButtonClick = function (id) {
            $.ajax({
                url: '/Home/Like/' + id,
                type: 'POST',
                success: function (data) {
                    alert("Beğendi");
                }
            });
        }

Comment: @FurkanBozdağ Code in comments is very difficult to read. Please edit your question with your view model so we can read it more easily. Knockout bindings are two directional and should always match.

Answer (score 1):

`this` context passed to the method will be your viewmodel, or whatever you have bound to the element. Inside `LikeButtonClick` you should be able to get the value of `MessageId` by referencing the property `this.MessageId()`.

If you want to pass a value to the click handler, you'll want to declare an inline function where you data-bind, or alternatively, bind the function with a context. Here the context is the main viewmodel:

```
data-bind="click: LikeButtonClick.bind($root,'green')"

var LikeButtonClick = function (src) {
        alert(src); // src='green' in this example
    }
```

Comment: How get  'green' in alert message ?

Comment: @FurkanBozdağ updated the example. I'd suggest reading through http://knockoutjs.com/documentation/event-binding.html for similar examples

Comment: thansk ıts work fine data-bind="click: LikeButtonClick.bind($root,MessageId)" ///

Comment: var LikeButtonClick = function (src) {
            alert(src);
        }